# Why is it impossible to evaluate $ \int_0^1\int_x^1 \sin ( y ^ 2 ) \, dy \, dx $ in this order?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Why is it impossible to evaluate the iterated integral $$ \int _ 0 ^ 1 \int _ x ^ 1 \sin ( y ^ 2 ) \, d y \, d x $$ in this order? I only was able to solve it after changing the order of integration.

Comment: it's not that it's impossible but it's much more difficult.  One order is straightforward the other relies upon something called special functions.  See Fresnel integrals

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Generally you should write out your questions using MathJax (see here: [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation) ) and not using pictures.

Comment: All continuous functions have antiderivatives, but most of them don't have antiderivatives that you can write down with a nice formula, and $y\mapsto\sin(y^2)$ is one of those. You could learn about Fresnel integral functions and use one of them. But this particular iterated integral is easier if you reverse the order. (And the relevant properties of Fresnel integral functions are probably only known because somebody reversed the order of some iterated integral to find them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we do not change the order of integration.
$$\int\sin ( y ^ 2 ) \, d y=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} y\right)$$
$$\int _ x ^ 1 \sin ( y ^ 2 ) \, d y=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right)-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}
   x\right) $$
Now, using one integration by parts,
$$\int S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}   x\right)\,dx=x S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} x\right)+\frac{\cos \left(x^2\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}$$
$$\int_0^1 S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}   x\right)\,dx=S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{\cos (1)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}$$ and all of that to arrive at
$$\int _ 0 ^ 1 \int _ x ^ 1 \sin ( y ^ 2 ) \, d y \, d x=\frac{1-\cos (1)}{2}$$

*What do you prefer (even knowing everything about Fresnel integrals) ?*